# HP Proliant DL380 Memory Error

Tags: memory, hp-proliant

Just bought 8x4GB memory DIMMs for HP DL380 G5 and after removing 8x2GB sticks and placing the new ones server doesn't boot and lights on all DIMMs error led. Memory is the correct PN from HP for this server. It's using 2xQuad Core processors. What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Many things could be wrong.. could you post the part # you purchased?

Comment: Provide MUCH more detail please

Comment: 466436-061 is the part number. Which details can be useful for you guys? Let me know and I will post it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a suggestion I found online it works.

I've started the server with only 4 DIMMs on 1A 3A 5B 7B and it booted, then I added the other 4 and worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think you bought wrong memory. I cannot found this part number under compatible parts in that server specification (http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/archives_North_America/12477_na_v37/12477_na.PDF). See page 36 of that document.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I can't find it either, but if you google around for that PN compatibility it shows available for DL380 G5 in multiple sites

Comment: Only trust the manufacturer's documentation.. at least if you're hoping to get support.